# htaccess mod_rewrite conflicting with zip file behavior

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following .htaccess on my root web folder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /foo-bar/$1 [L,NC]
```

On the same level i have a file foo.zip

Inside foo-bar i have a css file on a folder foo,so the physical path is  ~/foo-bar/foo/baz.css and the desired Web path would be www.mysite.com/foo/baz.css

So the file structure is:

ROOT: .htacces,foo-bar(folder) ,foo.zip

ROOT/foo-bar/: baz.css

If i leave the zip it doesn't work , outputing the following message:

```
The requested URL /foo-bar/redirect:/foo-bar/foo.zip/baz.css/baz.css was not found on this server.
```

Note that the zip is NOT on foo-bar its on the same level.

Simply renaming the zip solves the problem , but i would like to know the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your rule to:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!foo-bar/).*)$ foo-bar/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Didn't work, the crux of the question is on the Zip i guess, if i simply rename the zip, everything works as expected. If it has the same name of the folder on the URL and is on the root it breaks (also your rewriteRule was completely valid, it's just the zip thing that breaks it)

Comment: Options  -MultiViews solved it, thanks ! will google to understand what happened

Comment: Ya sure read it here: httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs before `mod_rewrite` and and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will server `/file.php`.